# Is there any disadvantage of buying a refurbished iPhone 6s/7?

Tags: iphone, hardware

I found some websites which sell "Refurbished" iPhone 6/6s/7 . Refurbished iPhones claim to work like "new". Is it really true?

Some people told me that - the **battery** in refurbished iPhone is **Not** new. Is it true?

Most of the websites give 60/90 days warranty for refurbished iPhones. Why don't they give 1 year warranty? Does it mean that refurbished iPhones don't last long because the phone was already used by someone else (which causes the phone to lose some of it's lifetime) ?

If there is **NO** disadvantage of a Refurbished iPhone (for eg: I will get 1 year warranty with Refurbished iPhone) , then what is the point of buying a Brand new iPhone spending extra money?

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you buy the iPhone. Generally it’s wrote when the battery is new.

On the Apple’s refurb, the batteries are new.

For the warranty, the websites offers 60/90 days because it’s not **NEW** iPhone, not because they’ll be decreasing shortly.
And the websites would tells you the *level* of the iPhone, if it gets scratch on the back, missing wire.

Comment: I did Not find find any website which specifically says about the condition of battery. I found a few websites that offers 1 year warranty with Refurbished(**used**) iPhones. Why do the other websites only offer 60/90 days or even No warranty?

Comment: Because its possible that there can be other issues with the device or because it has been repaired, it is no longer factory approved. Once you open a device, things like water-resistance and more are no longer the same as factory. Thats with any device. If you want a more guaranteed device, go with Apple. Just make sure that you get it from a store since the store may be willing to work with you if you are a local, and you have problems after purchase. Always check and see if you can get AppleCare warranty on the device. That is a plus if you can.

Comment: `Once you open a device, things like water-resistance and more are no longer the same as factory. Thats with any device.` So, iPhone refurbished by Apple also is NOT water-resistant?